# Counting Elements in $\text{GL}_2(F_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The professor in class today went over an example of counting the elements in $\text{GL}_2(F_p)$ (square matrices of size 2 by 2 with non zero determinant in a finite field with prime order $p$).

I'm confused about how he obtained $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ for $\text{GL}_2(F_p)$. He said, think about all possibilities except the zero vector in the first column gives the $(p^2-1)$. The second column can be anything except multiples of the first.

I'm confused though, in a finite field, can't a double counting error occur in the second column occur? For instance $\text{GL}_2(F_5)$ left the first column be $(1,2)^T$, the second columns to exclude are:
$$(1,2)^T \\ 2*(1,2)^T=(2,4)^T \\ 3*(1,2)^T=(3,6)^T = (3,1)^T \\ 4*(1,2)^T=(4,8)^T = (4,3)^T \\ 5*(1,2)^T=(5,10)^T=(1,2)^T$$
The last element gets double counted!

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
As max pointed out, the last term should be $(0,0)$, this creates a unique set of vectors to exclude. But I still don't know how to resolve the potential to double count if we scale the second column.

Comment: $5$ times anything is $0$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$

Comment: o whoops, is this the last term then?

Comment: also maybe my example is bad, but still, I dont know how to resolve the potential for double counting

Comment: Yep, $0$ is the missing term.  You just remove the whole subspace spanned by the first vector, which is a one-dimensional vectorspace over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. has $p$ elements.

Comment: ah i see, add this as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it won't be double counted is because if $c\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}=d\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}$ with $ c\neq d$, then this implies 
\begin{align*}
(c-d)u & = 0\\
(c-d)v & = 0
\end{align*}
Since we are in a field, so no zero divisors. Thus $u$ and $v$ both have to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simple: the determinant is non-zero if and only if it its column vectors (or its row vectors) are linearly independent.

Now you can obtain two linearly independent vectors by

- first choosing any non-zero vector. In $\mathbf F^2_p$ there are $p^2-1$ of them;
- then choosing a vector which is *not* collinear with the first chosen vector. There are $p$ multiples of this vector, so you choose one of the remaining $p^2-p$ vectors.

An easy generalisation shows that
$$\bigl|\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbf F_p)\bigr|=(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\dotsm(p^n-p^{n-1}).$$